# javascript code in external file

Tags: javascript

When I type in this code it either runs one or the other not both, and which ever comes first.

```
var topBox = document.getElementById('boxOne');
topBox.textContent = 'hello!'

var bottomSection = document.getElementById('bottomSection');
bottomSection.onmouseover = function() {
    bottomSection.textContent = '';
    bottomSection.style.padding = '';
};

bottomSection.onmouseout = function() {
    bottomSection.textContent = '';
    bottomSection.style.padding = '';
};
```

Comment: You type it in where? And what does it have to do with an "external file"?

Comment: Both functions do the same thing, how do you know which one is run and which one is not?

Comment: I'm building a site from scratch and have HTML plus JavaScript and CSS pages in sublime editor. If I have the 'box0ne' code first it just changes that element. Then if I change it to the 'bottomSection' code the at one works and the other doesn't, as if it stops and doesn't run the other code? Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function(){
  var topBox = document.getElementById('boxOne');
  topBox.textContent = 'hello!'

  var bottomSection = document.getElementById('bottomSection');
  bottomSection.onmouseover = function() {
    bottomSection.textContent = 'foo';
    bottomSection.style.padding = '';
  };

  bottomSection.onmouseout = function() {
    bottomSection.textContent = 'bar';
    bottomSection.style.padding = '';
  };
}())
```

```html
<div id="boxOne"></div>
<div id="bottomSection">I am bottom section</div>
```

It seems to work. Not sure what isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably may want to add event listener to listen for the mouseover/mouseout actions like so:

```
var bottomSection = document.getElementById("bottomSection");

bottomSection.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
bottomSection.textContent = '';
bottomSection.style.padding = '';
});
```

Comment: The two sections of code I have to put in separate files to get them both to work on the same site.

Comment: In that case, you can define the functions separately in you JS files and attach the `onmouseover/onmouseout` to the html element. For instance you could have: 
`function mouseOverAction() { 
/** Perform some action on mouse over */
}` 
Then in your html element you just add the mouse over action like so:
`<div id="bottomSection" onmouseover="mouseOverAction()">bottom section</div>`